# Generate or handle a missing argument in function in R

Tags: r, function

```
x = 1

simple <- function(p,q){
            return(q)
}

test = simple(x,y)

Error in simple(x, y) : object 'y' not found
```

**Please Note : Even if I don't create a variable "y", I should not get this error. Instead I want a message to be thrown saying "No data".**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try()` (or the more elaborate `tryCatch()` to do this.  For example,

```r
x = 1

simple <- function(p,q){
  q <- try(force(q), silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(q, "try-error")) {
    warning("No data")
    q <- NULL
  }
  return(q)
}

test = simple(x,y)
#> Warning in simple(x, y): No data
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What the `force()` function does is evaluate the argument.  If that fails, it returns an error:  but `try()` catches that.  (You don't actually need to call `force(q)`, it would be enough to use `try(q)`, but I think the explicit version is clearer.)